# Getting null pointer exception on callbackmanager

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using facebook SDK. When logging, i'm getting a nullpointer exception,

```
 LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                System.out.println("onSuccess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception)
            {
                Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The error is raising from the method onActivityResult on the second line, 
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);.

Part of stacktrace:

```
06-20 14:07:52.253  21310-21310/com.itspirits.fbchatdownloader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.itspirits.fbchatdownloader, PID: 21310
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.itspirits.fbchatdownloader/com.itspirits.fbchatdownloader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.itspirits.fbchatdownloader.MainActivity$1.onError(MainActivity.java:53)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:507)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:192)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:140)
        at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
        at com.itspirits.fbchatdownloader.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Random thought move `callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();` under `onCreate(...)`

Comment: it was like this before, i just tested it up, yet same results

Comment: I saw this crash happen once in crashlytics, but can't reproduce. Could you provide any insight into how to reproduce the crash? I'm always able to login with facebook successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my code for Facebook login.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_photos, user_friends"));
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile1, Profile profile) {

                            final String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();

                            String profileImgUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large";
                            Log.d("Facebook ", "userId : " + userId);
                            final String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                            Log.d("Facebooklog ", "Token " + token);
                            if (profile == null) return;
                            String name = profile.getName();
                        }
                    };
                    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("facebook - onCancel", "cancelled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    Log.d("facebook - onError", e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Is  callbackManager null? 
Is data null? (Unlikely)

You can do some simple debuging like printing the variables before use to see for yourself what and when is null :-)

Comment: this is the issue, neither data, requestCode or resultCode is null

Comment: Well something has to be, Is it the full stack above?

Comment: Full stacktrace added

Comment: Just saying, (I am strugling to find whats wrong D:) but i noticed line 3 where it says "who=null" :/
Also how is the package your code is in called?

Comment: I just found it, i'm sorry, it's a mega silly error, i forgot to add keyhashes, actually, it's my first android app using facebook sdk :/

Comment: Dont be sorry! we are here to help and we all have had such a silly error messing with our heads! :- )